# NodeJS: DistrictId undefined on frontend endpoint when passed from the backend

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs

I want to pass the district name parameter from the backend into the api endpoint on the frontend. In basic terms,to display the getAllHouseholds from the backend it should depend on the district name passed into the endpoint, and when the district name changes,it should render the getAllHouseholds of that district. The district attribute has a district_id

Here is the frontend code:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import React, { useEffect, useState, useContext } from "react";
import { Table, Spin, Alert } from "antd";
import axios from "axios";
import AppContext from "../context/appContext";


const Households = ({ history, district }) => {

  const clients = useContext(AppContext);
  const households = clients.householdData.data;

  const [totalPages, setTotalPages] = useState(1);
  const [household, setHouseholds] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [districtId, setDistrictId] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchHouseholds();
    console.log(fetchHouseholds);
  }, []);

  console.log("This districtId is: ", district);

  const fetchHouseholds = async (page) => {
    setLoading(true);
     axios.get(
        `${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER}/household/district/${districtId}`
      ).then((res) => {
        setHouseholds(res.data.data);
        setTotalPages(res.data.totalPages);
        setLoading(false);
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        setLoading(false);
        setError(err);
      });
    }   

const columns = [
  {
    title: 'Screened',
    dataIndex: 'screened',
    render: (value) => (
      <a className="btn btn-link btn-success btn-just-icon like">
        <i className="material-icons">{value === true ? "check" : "close"}</i>
      </a>
    ),
  },
  {
    title: 'Facility',
    dataIndex: 'facility',
  },
  {
    title: 'Household ID',
    dataIndex: 'household_id',
  },
  {
    title: 'Caregiver',
    dataIndex: 'caregiver_name',
  },
  {
    title: 'Caseworker',
    dataIndex: 'caseworker_name',
  },
  {
    title: 'Caseworker phone',
    dataIndex: 'phone',
  },
  {
    title: 'Last edited',
    dataIndex: 'dateEdited',
  },
  {
    title: '',
    render: (_, record) => (
      <Link to={`/household/${record.json._id}`} className="btn btn-link btn-info btn-just-icon like">
        <i className="material-icons">visibility</i>
      </Link>
    ),
  },
];

const data = households?.map((house) => ({
  key: house.json._id,
  screened: house.json.attributes.screened,
  facility: house.json.attributes.facility,
  household_id: house.json.attributes.household_id,
  caregiver_name: house.json.attributes.caregiver_name,
  caseworker_name: house.json.attributes.caseworker_name,
  phone: house.json.attributes.phone,
  dateEdited: house.json.attributes.dateEdited,
}));

  return (
    <>
    <div className="card">
      <div className="card-header-info">
        <h4 className="card-title ">Households</h4>
      </div>
      <div className="card-body">
        {loading ? (
          <Spin />
        ) : error ? (
          <Alert message={error} type="error" />
        ) : (
          <Table
          columns={columns}
            dataSource={data}
            rowKey="_id"
            onRow={(record) => {
              return {
                onClick: () => history.push(`/household/${record._id}`),
              };
            }}            
          loading={loading}
          pagination={{
            pageSize: 10,
            total: totalPages,
            onChange: (page) => {
              fetchHouseholds(page);
            },
          }}
        ></Table>
      )}
      </div>
    </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Households;
```

I tried to pass the districtId into the endpoint on the frontend but it returned the districtId as undefined.

Comment: Can you post your `/household/district/${districtId}` route declaration on the server?

Comment: Alright here it is:                                                                                                     
    `router
  .route("/district/:district")
  .get(
    householdController.getAllHouseholds
  );`